# Electron : Module version mismatch. Expected 50, got 48

Tags: node.js, electron

So I am trying to bridge objective c and node.js using 'nodobjc' :

```
var $ = require('NodObjC')
$.framework('Foundation')
var pool = $.NSAutoreleasePool('alloc')('init')
var string = $.NSString('stringWithUTF8String', 'Hello Objective-C World!')
console.log(string)
pool('drain')
```

After adding this, I am getting this exception :

> Module version mismatch. Expected 50, got 48.

I am using Node v7.1.0 & NPM 3.10.9.
I checked [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) to see if anything is out of date, but there's nothing with a NODE_MODULE_VERSION of 50. 
What is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the native module against your current node version?

Comment: @JensHabegger : I solved it by runing this : npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=1.3.1 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --build-from-source Rebuilt it using a different target version and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by runing this :

`npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=1.3.1 --disturl=atom.io/download/atom-shell --build-from-source`

Rebuilt it using a different target version and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

I was facing similar problem few days ago, and here's how i fixed it:

```
npm install electron-rebuild --save-dev
```

then call (Windows)

```
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

or (Linux, Mac)

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

Basically you need to rebuild electron every time you add new native module to app.

Comment: Szydlo : Thanks! I solved it by runing this :  

`npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=1.3.1 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --build-from-source`

Rebuilt it using a different target version and it worked!